# I want to make images stick together in Bootstrap but I can't

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my images like these in Bootstrap:

[image: ideal]

But they look like this:

[image: not ideal]

here's the code [nothing much important]:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="example">
<img class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="example">
<img class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="example">
<img class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="example">
```

Comment: This is really 2 questions. I'd recommend splitting them up.

Comment: The "ideal" version looks like the images will be different sizes. Do you just want them to be next to each other on the same line, or for them to shuffle themselves around so they fit in a square, or what?

Comment: Also, a simple jsFiddle would be useful to get us started on this problem.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I set their size different on purpose, I want them to be like this.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat how should I use that?

Comment: Okay. If you know ahead of time the size of each image, you can just slot them together with whatever CSS you like. If you don't know the size of each image, then you'd have to sort that out at runtime using a JS library like [Masonry](http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/get-started-jquery-masonry-8123019).

Comment: I know the size of each one, I don't know what to do to put them together like ideal and secondly bring this group of images to the center of the page. @Whothehellisthat please help me

Comment: Okay, you should be able to do it just using html and css. If you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the images (at the correct sizes) in the page that would be useful. You can just make a new fiddle, paste in code into the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript boxes, hit Run, and it'll show you the page you built. Then press "Save" or "Update", and copy the url from the address bar, and paste it in your post. Then we can see what you've got so far and make our own changes.

Comment: What is the requirement for Bootstrap here? will these images be in a single bootstrap column? You can pack images together like this using flex-box (although they will be in column layout, not row). you don't necessarily need Masonry or similar if that is ok. [example](http://codepen.io/pythagoras1357/pen/ORrbwR)

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left`

```
img{

    float:left;

    }
```